ReadOnlyError(You can't write against a read only replica) for redis helm chart . how to configure the services to use master & worker for set and get
Name and Version
bitnami/redis 7.2.5
What architecture are you using?
None
What steps will reproduce the bug?
Hi, i have a kubernetes cluster spinned up with kuberadm.
now i have a redis cluster inside it which is conigured using redis-sentinel helm chart.
and there are 3 redis pods one of them is a master.
i am accessing it from my service via
redis-sentinel.default.svc.cluster.local
Now my requests from service are randomly going to master and worker. and throwing Readonly error
how can i configure it that all the SETs go to master and Gets go to worker?
Are you using any custom parameters or values?
global:
redis:
password: "my-password"

architecture: "replication"
auth:
enabled: true

replica:
replicaCount: 3
persistence:
enabled: true
storageClass: "ebs-sc"
size: 5Gi

sentinel:
enabled: true
replicas: 3

master:
persistence:
enabled: true
storageClass: "ebs-sc"
size: 5Gi

replica:
persistence:
enabled: true
storageClass: "ebs-sc"
size: 5Gi

What is the expected behavior?
set requests go to master and get requests go to worker
What do you see instead?
requests are going randomly to master and worker

did you find any solution to this?

@MustafaGüven kinda yes.
sorry for late reply.
redis sentinel has discover function,
you can find that here: https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.2/connections.html
So when I was running the cluster, every pod has two containers, 1 redis on 6379 and 1 sentinel on 26379.
I connected to redis sentinel over port 26379 in my code instead of redis, and got the master , and connected to master for set requests and replica for get requests.
as the master may change, so I wrote a wrapper function which fetches the master or replica for every request.
